# View other user's terminal FreeBSD

Tags: view, terminal, freebsd

I do not remember how to do this, but I seem to recall that this is possible:

I want to view other logged in users' terminals (TTY), showing all of what users do when I look at their terminals. How would I connect to their terminals?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this BSD Guide answer your question?

[Watch Terminal Activity](http://www.bsdguides.org/2005/watch-terminal-activity/)

Answer (score 0):

In order to use watch, you must have the snp (snoop device) module installed when you build your kernel.